# Not sure if isekai but MC dies and while he's dying he says he wants to study magic

Tags: story-identification, manga

I believe he was reincarnated as royalty I think the youngest prince and he opens a forbidden book and gets a majin as a helper or summon. I read this online not sure what style. The earliest memory is that he blows a hole into the ozone layer and closed space and I think he said "whew space almost leaked in". Also he was in a dungeon with an adventurer and practically masters Martial arts. He's also I think unbeatable in magic. It's a manga I believe.

Comment: In an earlier version of the question you said he might be *"a baron or a duke"*. Is that no longer the case?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: That was I think before he reincarnated but I'm not sure about that so I decided to leave it out

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like [Tensei Shitara dai Nana Ouji dattanode, Kimamani Majutsu o Kiwamemasu](https://mangadex.org/title/52827/tensei-shitara-dai-nana-ouji-dattanode-kimamani-majutsu-o-kiwamemasu)

> A magic freak's life came to an end after a dreadful encounter with
> the nobles who ended his life with a powerful spell. His last wish,
> being able to study and master more magic, has been answered when he
> was reincarnated as Lloyd de Saloom, the 7th prince of Saloom Kingdom.
> Now he'll be able to perfect his magic as he pleases...

From [MangaDex](https://mangadex.org/title/52827/tensei-shitara-dai-nana-ouji-dattanode-kimamani-majutsu-o-kiwamemasu)

He is killed by a noble, and dies thinking that the noble's magic is beautiful.

He reincarnates as a extremely talented mage. He finds the Majin at chapter 1, in the castle library, and "seals" it in his body.

He blows the hole in the ozone layer, showing the stratosphere, in chapter 2, while trying multiple incantations, using both his mouth and the majin's.

Comment: Huh. I didn't know this one had come up before. ^_^ I was going to provide it as an answer to a recently closed (very short) question!