# Manga about a male student of magic who was killed by a noble, and reborn as a noble child

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga

This manga is about a male student who loved magic and studied it a lot. He was killed by a high ranking noble and then reborn as a noble child prodigy. I think he has a goat pet.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please have a look at [this page](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question), and try to think of any other details about this story that you can recall. If you do remember anything else, you can [edit] that information into your answer to improve it (clarifying _when_ you read this story would be a good start). Also, if you know of any manga with a similar premise that aren't the one you're looking for, it would help to list those in your question as well, so we know not to submit those as answers.

Comment: If I were paranoid, I would say this surge of these 2-liners asian ID questions are a way to make obfuscated advertisement of unknown works.

Comment: I actually think I read this one recently...

Comment: If it's the one in thinking of, he has several older brothers after reincarnation, and he has to work to not overshadow them. He just wants to study magic, but they keep making him practice swordfighting or go outside. He has a buzzing bodyguard who makes him bathe with her for fanservice. The goat familiar is a powerful locked demon from the castle library who can double chant Magic due to having two mouths.

Comment: Ah! *I was reincarnated as the 7th Prince so I will perfect my magic as I please*

Comment: :) Also the answer to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/241412/not-sure-if-isekai-but-mc-dies-and-while-hes-dying-he-says-he-wants-to-study-ma, but not accepted.

Comment: So that is the correct answer?

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 5):

As per the comments above, and confirmed by the querent, this is *[I was reincarnated as the 7th Prince so I will perfect my magic as I please](https://myanimelist.net/manga/129631/Tensei_shitara_Dainana_Ouji_Datta_node_Kimama_ni_Majutsu_wo_Kiwamemasu)*, original title *Tensei Shitara dai Nana Ouji dattanode, Kimamani Majutsu o Kiwamemasu*.

> A magic nerd's life came to an end after a dreadful encounter with the nobles who ended his life with a powerful spell. His last wish, being able to study and master more magic, has been answered when he was reincarnated as Lloyd de Saloom, the 7th prince of Saloom Kingdom. Now he'll be able to perfect his magic as he pleases...

Lloyd's "familiar" is actually a Majin (demon) that was sealed in the library, but it indeed agrees to be his familiar, and assumes a smaller, cuter, form. The chief crux of the plot is that Lloyd, possessed of both great magical potential due to his bloodline, and great knowledge from his prior life, is comically overpowered, but he's in the body of a child, and tries to hide his talents. There's a fair amount of innocent fanservice, as his female bodyguard keeps dragging him into the baths with her. Another possibly notable aspect is that, as seen on the cover, he's fairly androgynous in appearance and dress in the series.

[image: Front cover of the first volume of the manga, showing Lloyd with his familiar]