# I’m looking for a manga with a crippled MC

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic

So in the manga I’m looking for, the MC is a man who was crippled and couldn’t get out of his wheelchair and is killed by a mage, but he is reborn as a noble and then tries to learn as much magic as possible, and becomes the strongest in the world. Throughout the story (at least to the point that I’ve read) he is still a child, and near the beginning of the story he blows a home in the sky. Ex info: he has a maid/aid whose name is Silvia or Silva. Thank you!

Comment: Possible dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/259487/a-powerful-mage-gets-reincarnated-as-the-youngest-prince-whos-overpowered-from - I don't remember a wheelchair, but everything else matches

Comment: Indeed, no wheelchair, although it does open on him crawling on the ground due to his wounds.

Comment: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

I am in agreement with Valorum that this is likely *Tensei Shitara dai Nana Ouji dattanode, Kimamani Majutsu o Kiwamemasu*, or *[I was reincarnated as the 7th Prince so I will perfect my magic as I please](https://myanimelist.net/manga/129631/Tensei_shitara_Dainana_Ouji_Datta_node_Kimama_ni_Majutsu_wo_Kiwamemasu)* as per [A powerful mage gets reincarnated as the youngest prince who's overpowered from birth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/259487/a-powerful-mage-gets-reincarnated-as-the-youngest-prince-whos-overpowered-from).

[image: Front cover of Tensei Shitara dai Nana Ouji dattanode, Kimamani Majutsu o Kiwamemasu]

> A magic nerd's life came to an end after a dreadful encounter with the nobles who ended his life with a powerful spell. His last wish, being able to study and master more magic, has been answered when he was reincarnated as Lloyd de Saloom, the 7th prince of Saloom Kingdom. Now he'll be able to perfect his magic as he pleases...

He is not explicitly crippled at the beginning of the manga, but he is reduced to crawling due to his injuries before the fatal blow happens. He wakes up as a baby, and not realizing his situation, he fires off a "weak fire blast" that blows a hole in the roof. His maid/sword-trainer is indeed named Silpha.

[image: The provider crawling due to their injuries] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

[image: Lloyd internally commenting on how he needs to take Silpha seriously] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>