# Protagonist in cave found a lich and one girl with martial arts tries to help him, but she fails and the protagonist helps her

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I'm looking for a manga where the protagonist goes into a cave and meets a lich, and a girl appears who knows martial arts (it takes place in an isekai).

I don't remember exactly but she gets beaten and the protagonist, being very strong, finishes it quickly and then she starts following him wanting him to teach her.

It's been about 2 years since I’ve read it and I read it on mangalivre.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: It's been about 2 years and I read it on mangalivre

Comment: I've closed your question as a duplicate, but it was not a bad question. :) If nothing else, what you provided let me get it very quickly. This is just part of how we organize things. You will still get points for people upvoting your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might this be *Tensei Shitara dai Nana Ouji dattanode, Kimamani Majutsu o Kiwamemasu*, or *[I was reincarnated as the 7th Prince so I will perfect my magic as I please](https://myanimelist.net/manga/129631/Tensei_shitara_Dainana_Ouji_Datta_node_Kimama_ni_Majutsu_wo_Kiwamemasu)* as per [A powerful mage gets reincarnated as the youngest prince who's overpowered from birth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/259487/)?

[image: Front cover of Tensei Shitara dai Nana Ouji dattanode, Kimamani Majutsu o Kiwamemasu]

> A magic nerd's life came to an end after a dreadful encounter with the nobles who ended his life with a powerful spell. His last wish, being able to study and master more magic, has been answered when he was reincarnated as Lloyd de Saloom, the 7th prince of Saloom Kingdom. Now he'll be able to perfect his magic as he pleases...

He meets the female martial artist in Chapter 4, and fights the lich in Chapters 5 and 6, rescuing her.

[image: The lich, split in half by his attack] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

[image: Splitting the "loot" between them] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>